# sum after subtracting first element of particular column with all the elements of another column and repeat with 2 element and so on in R programming

Tags: r, datetime, conditional-statements, aggregate

I would like to sum post subtracting all elements of datestamp-1 with 1st element of datestamp-2, and repeat the same for 2nd element of datestamp-2 and so on in R

```
datestamp1 datestamp2 load_percent
2019-05-28 2019-05-25 0.01883
2019-05-29 2019-05-26 0.72340
```

Expected result is as mentioned below.

```
datestamp1 datestamp2 weighted_index
2019-05-28 2019-05-25 2.95
2019-05-29 2019-05-26 2.20
```

Logic being

```
1. 2019-05-28 - 2019-05-25 = 3 * 0.01 = 0.056 
2. 2019-05-29 - 2019-05-25 = 4 * 0.72 = 2.893
```

sum of 0.056 and 2.893 is 2.95

similarly

```
3. 2019-05-28 - 2019-05-26 = 2 * 0.01 = 0.037
4. 2019-05-29 - 2019-05-26 = 3 * 0.72 = 2.170
```

and sum of 0.037 and 2.170 is 2.20

Comment: In the calculation `(3 * 0.01) + (4 * 0.72)` from where did `0.01` and `0.72` come?

Comment: yes it is (3*0.01)+(4*0.72) and 0.01 and 0.72 are given values in the dataframe

Comment: Just do `with(df, sum(difftime(datestamp1 - datestamp2, unit = 'days') * load_percent)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sapply` you can do

```
df$weighted_index <- sapply(df$datestamp2, function(x) 
                            sum((df$datestamp1 - x) * df$load_percent))

df
#  datestamp1 datestamp2 load_percent weighted_index
#1 2019-05-28 2019-05-25      0.01883        2.95009
#2 2019-05-29 2019-05-26      0.72340        2.20786
```

Make sure that your columns `datestamp1` and `datestamp2` are of `Date` class. If they are not first convert them to date and then use the above code.

```
 df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], as.Date)
```

Comment: Many thanks, also one more clarifications, if there are 2 more date stamps datestamp3 and 4 and i want to check for condition if datestamp4-datestamp3 is greater than 3 hours, then sum(df$datestamp1-x)*load_percent) else sum((df$datestamp1-x)+1)*load_percent),  trying to acheive this but not able to figure out how to fit ifelse

Comment: @VasukiRao you could create 2 separate objects. `a1 <- sapply(df$datestamp2, function(x) sum((df$datestamp1 - x) * df$load_percent))` and `a2 <- sapply(df$datestamp2, function(x) sum((df$datestamp1-x+1)* df$load_percent))` and then use `ifelse(difftime(df$datestamp4,df$datestamp3, units = "hours") > 3, a1, a2)` Make sure that `datestamp4` and `datestamp3` are of class `POSIXct`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `outer` to get the difference between the two date columns, then get the `colSums` of the product with 'load_percent'

```
df1$weighted_index <- with(df1, colSums(outer(datestamp1, 
          datestamp2, FUN = `-` ) * load_percent))

df1
#  datestamp1 datestamp2 load_percent weighted_index
#1 2019-05-28 2019-05-25      0.01883        2.95009
#2 2019-05-29 2019-05-26      0.72340        2.20786
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(datestamp1 = structure(c(18044, 18045), class = "Date"), 
    datestamp2 = structure(c(18041, 18042), class = "Date"), 
    load_percent = c(0.01883, 0.7234)), row.names = c(NA, -2L
), class = "data.frame")
```